# Message "28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx\", user \"User", database \"databasename\", SSL off"

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, ssl, heroku, npgsql

I 'm trying to connect postgresql database remotely ( Heroku ). 
I use ASP Web api but always i have the same exception :Message "28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx\", user \"User", database \"databasename\", SSL off"
I search some solution by editing the pg_hba.conf file and i add  : 
host    databasename    username    xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx     md5
and no change .

Answer (score 27):

Add **sslmode=Require;** and **Trust Server Certificate=true;** in your connection string.It will work for sure.

Comment: This is it Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Heroku Postgres requires client connections are made with SSL. Configure your application to require SSL on database connections and this error will go away.

Answer (score 2):

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust

or
 host all all 192.168.0.0/24 trust

of course, you also need

```
listen_address = '*'
```